# What does the character on Trip's shirt mean?

Tags: ps3, enslaved-odyssey-to-the-west

What does the character on Trip's shirt mean in "Enslaved: Odyssey to the West"?

[image]

Comment: (I would have used the tag "Enslaved" but there wasn't one.)

Answer (score 3):

Trip's full name in the game is Tripitaka. The character on her shirt is [经 (jing), short for 经典 (jing dian), which means "classical scripture"](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%BB%8F%E5%85%B8) in Chinese. In Chinese Buddhism, [the canonical scriptures are called Tripitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka#The_three_categories). Thus, Jing essentially means Trip's name itself.